# How to make select operator behave similar to the bash in zsh

Tags: select, zsh

I'm trying to use next code in zsh:

```
select var in $list; do
  if [ x"$var" != x"" ]; then
    echo $var
    return
  fi
done
```

In bash that would result to something like this:

1. First
2. Second
3. Third

But in zsh I get this:

1. First          3. Third
2. Second

How could I make it to print each variant on the new line?

Comment: Using `zsh`, you don't need to use the ancient hack to guard against empty strings. Just use `if [[ -n $var ]]`.

Comment: `[[ -n   ]]` is still malformed, in case anyone uses prepared statements. Zsh phrases it as `unknown condition: -n`, instead of reporting the missing argument, providing a default `[[ -n ]] == [[ -n "" ]]`, or equiv. the nullary `[[ -n ]] == false`. If any of that changed, it would probably mean yet another environment variable to slide between strict/convenient/compatible/portable. (Hence "ancient hacks" - legacy is cumbersome but sometimes more portable, etc. as shells diverge. It's not a defense, I just know Zsh's features and quirks mean  I trip for a while in Bash.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Zsh manual:

```
 COLUMNS <S>
     The number of columns for this terminal session.  
     Used for printing select lists and for the line editor.
```

This works here:

```
emulate -L zsh
setopt sh_word_split
# if not running in a separate shell, you'll want to restore the old value
export COLUMNS=1
list="first second third"
select var in $list; do
  if [ x"$var" != x"" ]; then
    echo $var
  return
  fi
done
```

Do restore the old value of COLUMNS if running on your main interactive shell.

Comment: What is the `x""` syntax? I'm having a hard time searching for it.

Comment: That is ordinary string concatination. It works around some edge cases when comparing an empty string as far as I know. x"$var" == x means "$var" must be empty without having to have an empty string.